# VS2015 CSS menu items publish in a different color

Tags: css, visual-studio

My environment is Windows10 and VS2015. I have a black page header in site master, and for contrast I use gold letters for menu item names, but when I publish, my menu items appear dark blue and are unreadable. I attach images of both set of letters and my CSS. I have not experienced this before and would appreciate a solution[image: Development menu]
[image: Production menu]
[image: Css used for both]

Comment: Use the dev tools to see where the color is coming from.

Comment: Also, use `:hover`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how do I "Use the dev tools to see where the color is coming from" on a production site?  This morning the colors are rendering correctly in IE and FF, but still blue in Chrome. The site is iilseeker.com and selecting "Run Correlation" on the main menu takes you to the backend website which has the color problem.

Comment: Right-click the element in Chrome and click Inspect.  It will show all relevant CSS.

Comment: That's cool, thanks. Right now all the browsers are rendering perfectly; why, I will never know!

Comment: SLaks, please could you take a look at "IIS 10 with 2 websites"? It has bugged me for months and as a guru I am hoping you may know enough about IIS to help. Thanks!